# javascript: how do we track the total number of objects (any object will be counted) in the page

Tags: javascript, object, profiling, tracking

I want to track the total number of objects created in the page (i'm testing/analysing something).

Is it possible to do so? (like if i press a button it will alert 1300 if 1300 objects are created)

Btw I'm not checking how many objects currently exists, im tracking the total number of objects "ever created".

I was thinking of modifying the **Object.prototype.constructor** and add some tracking mechanism there but its not a writable property

Edit:
I'm trying to find out if i run this code:

```
var Test=function(){
  return {};
};
//start tracker
new Test();
//end tracker
```

how many objects are created between // start tracker and //end tracker (i'm suspecting 2 objects, but i just want to be sure)

Comment: "Objects" as in "DOM Elements" or "JavaScript variables"? If it's variables it's impossible.

Comment: @minitech Well, you can store (the reference of) a DOM element inside a JavaScript variable `:)`

Comment: What if five variables refer to the same object?

Comment: *"objects created in the page"* - How?

Comment: @SLaks that would be 1 count. sorry if my previous reply was misleading.

Comment: @SLaks Heys I've updated the question btw

Comment: @Pacerier Why do you think that 2 objects are created?

Comment: @Šime Vidas because i think when we do a new Test() an object is created even before the first line of Test is ran, the second object apparently is the object literal that was returned

Comment: @Pacerier Yes, that's true. Read here: http://es5.github.com/#x13.2.2

Comment: @Šime Vidas k cool put that as answer thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a function `f` is called as a constructor (`new f()`), a new object is created and provided as the `this` value for the call. Read about the `[[Construct]]` internal method [here](http://es5.github.com/#x13.2.2).

Therefore, `new Test()` will create (at least) 2 objects:

- an object that is created automatically (and bound to `this`)
- an object that is created by your object literal expression (`{}`)

Answer (score 1):

The Chrome developer tools include a "heap profiler" which can tell you how many objects of each type *currently* exist, and how much memory they're using.

Comment: in my script i had 1 or at most 2 objects. that heap profiler shows 260 objects.. I edited my tests and added more "objects" but its still 260 objects.